# using assimp to load fbx animation data

Tags: fbx, assimp

Recently I just read *Introduction to 3D Game Programming with Directx 11*,and i trying to using the example in chapter 25 to load my own model.So after I skin a model and export data in .fbx format,I try to load bone and animation data and get wrong results.So,

1.I just copy the offset matrix to my own structure and transpose it,is this ok?

```
for (auto & s: names)
{
    auto index = maps[s];
    auto m = matrixmaps[s];
    memcpy(offset.float1d, m, sizeof(float)* 16);
    TransposeMatrix(offset);
    Offsets[index] = offset;
}
```

2.I found that the root bone(Bip001) has zero key frame,so I check node hierarchy of the data assimp loaded,and I notice that the bone hierarchy is just as below:

```
   |_RootNode
      |_Bip001_$AssimpFbx$_Translation
        |_Bip001_$AssimpFbx$_PreRotation
          |_Bip001_$AssimpFbx$_Rotation
            |_Bip001_$AssimpFbx$_Scaling
              |_Bip001
                |_Bip001 Footsteps
                |_Bip001 Pelvis
                  |_Bip001 Spine
                    |_Bip001 Spine1
                    | |_Bip001 Spine2
                    |   |_Bip001 Spine3
                    |     |_Bip001 Neck
                    |       |_Bip001 L Clavicle
                    |       | |_Bip001 L UpperArm
                    |       |   |_Bip001 L Forearm
                    |       |     |_Bip001 L Hand
                    |       |       |_Bip001 L Finger0
                    |       |         |_Bip001 L Finger0Nub
                    |       |_Bip001 R Clavicle
                    |       | |_Bip001 R UpperArm
                    |       |   |_Bip001 R Forearm
                    |       |     |_Bip001 R Hand
                    |       |       |_Bip001 R Finger0
                    |       |         |_Bip001 R Finger0Nub
                    |       |_Bip001 Head
                    |         |_Bip001 HeadNub
                    |_Bip001 L Thigh
                    | |_Bip001 L Calf
                    |   |_Bip001 L Foot
                    |     |_Bip001 L Toe0
                    |       |_Bip001 L Toe01
                    |         |_Bip001 L Toe02
                    |           |_Bip001 L Toe0Nub
                    |_Bip001 R Thigh
                      |_Bip001 R Calf
                        |_Bip001 R Foot
                          |_Bip001 R Toe0
                            |_Bip001 R Toe01
                              |_Bip001 R Toe02
                                |_Bip001 R Toe0Nub
```

How should I deal with the parent of node Bip001,should I copy positionkeys,rotationkeys and scalingkeys from these node to Bip001?
Please help me figure it out.Thank you very much.

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I'm having the exact same problem : (

Answer (score 0):

For the second problem, setting AI_CONFIG_IMPORT_FBX_PRESERVE_PIVOTS to false works for me.